# How to remove white space after a comma from user entered data using PHP

Tags: php

How can I remove empty space after a comma `,` that has no words using PHP.

Here is an entry.

```
apple pie,      cherry   ,         ,       pears,      crumb cake        ,         ,
```

And Here is what I get so far.

```
apple pie, cherry, , pears, crumb cake,
```

And here is the desired output I want.

```
apple pie, cherry, pears, crumb cake
```

And here is the PHP code I got so far.

```
$words = preg_split('/,/', filter_var($words, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_NO_ENCODE_QUOTES), -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
$words = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $words);
$words = array_map('trim', $words)
```

Comment: xPx, WPSE is for WordPress specific questions. This is purely a PHP post which would be more fitting for Stack Overflow. This question could be migrated there by a moderator as well.

Answer (score 5):

one liner fun:

```
$words = array_filter(array_map('trim',explode(',',$words)))
```

Comment: Was just about to post this. The `array_filter` without a callback is one of the most useful PHP tricks I've come across.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is a WordPress question in particular, but you can sanitize the data by exploding it into an array by the commas and then trim / remove any empty values.

```
$words = 'apple pie, , cherry, pears, ,';
$words_array = explode(',', $words);
$clean_words_array = array();
foreach($words_array as $word) {
    if (!empty(trim($word))) {
        $clean_words_array[] = trim($word);
    }
}

// you now have an array with words
// you can put them back in a comma separated string
// using the implode() function if you want
```